# How long to cook syrup for Baklava?

Tags: baking, temperature, sugar, syrup

I want to make Baklava, but I do not know how long to cook the syrup for.

Some websites say 4-5 minutes, some say 20 minutes, and I am clueless...

**I am using an 8x8 pan, 7 oz of white sugar and 7 oz of water.**

Is there a specific temperature I should cook it to?

Edit:

To avoid confusion - I am not looking for a simple syrup recipe, like the ones used to flavor drinks or keep cakes moist.
I need a "light syrup", used for oriental sweets (as I've read), and most of the recipes call for "5 minutes of gentle boiling", so that is my best bet so far.

Comment: Related question: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12586/how-can-i-know-when-a-thick-simple-syrup-is-done-cooking?rq=1

Comment: I have seen this, and I thank you for the link, but I need more help than "as soon as there is no visible sugar in the water". I find that to be somewhat too vague for someone who has never made this (like me), so a temperature or a sugar cooking stage would be better for me. Thank you again!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I know when a thick simple syrup is done cooking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12586/how-can-i-know-when-a-thick-simple-syrup-is-done-cooking)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no specific temperature you need to reach. Once the sugar is dissolved (which will happen well below boiling temperature) you’re done.

Answer (score 1):

You can test whether the sugar is dissolved by taking a tiny amount of the syrup and rubbing it in between your fingers.

If you heat the syrup for too long, you will get it to be a slightly yellow color.